# How to write dynamic mock data for each test using jest.mock

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm mocking a custom hook and while I'm able to do it with static data at the top of my test file in jest, I want to be able to do it on a per test bases. For eample on each test I want to be able to return different mock data. How would I go about restructuring this yo allow for returning  different data on each test.

```
const mocked_StartCapture= jest.fn()

jest.mock('@myModules/screen-hook', () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual('@myModules/screen-hook') as any),
  useScreenHook: () => ({
    startCapture: () => mocked_StartCapture,
    viewableData: () => ({
      height: 1500,
      width: 1600,
      image:
        '00w0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQiVBORAAABkBAMAAACCzIhnAAAAG1BMVEWJiob',
    }),
  }),
}))

test('renders Component', async () => {
 /// Update mock to use different startCapture and viewableData functions. 
  const result = render(<Screen/>)
  expect(result).toBeDefined()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try sth like this:

```js
cosnt mockViewableData = jest.fn.mockReturnValue({
  height: 1500,
  width: 1600,
  image: '00w0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQiVBORAAABkBAMAAACCzIhnAAAAG1BMVEWJiob',
}));
const mockStartCapture = jest.fn();
jest.mock('@myModules/screen-hook', () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual('@myModules/screen-hook') as any),
  useScreenHook: () => ({
    startCapture: () => mockStartCapture(),
    viewableData: () => mockViewableData(),
  }),
}));
```

And then in tests:

```js
test('renders Component', async () => {
  /// Update mock to use different startCapture and viewableData functions. 
  mockStartCapture.mockReturnValue({ whatever: "you need" });
  mockViewableData.mockReturnValue({ height: 42, width: 42, image: 'something' });

  const result = render(<Screen/>)
  expect(result).toBeDefined()
})
```